# Excel "Run-time error '424': Object required" When calling a boolean function

Tags: vba, excel

VBA novice and trying to learn as much as I can, so please don't hesitate to over-inform.

**Goal:** Within a sub, call a function that returns a boolean value of true when two objects overlap. The idea is for the user to be able to drag and drop shapes within each other in order to easily create a hierarchy.

**Problem:** I am receiving the *"Object required"* error as stated in the title on the commented line. RecA and RecB are the shapes in question defined in the arguments of the function. The function, named *"Overlap"*, is in Module1.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Function_Result As Boolean
    Function_Result = Overlap(RecA, RecB) '<--------!

    If Function_Result = True Then
            MsgBox ("swiggity swooty")
    End If
End Sub
```

From research I have only been able to find the solution of using the `set` modifier preceding `Function_Result` which I have tried (along with other possible solutions) to no avail.

If the function code is at all helpful, let me know and I can add it to this post.

Excel 2010

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are these shapes defined? If these shapes are on a worksheet, and that's all the code you have in CommandButton1_Click() (which I think should be Private, not public) then I can tell you that VBA doesn't recognize RecA and RecB as anything other than empty variables.

Comment: At the very least, post the header of `Overlap`, and where/how `RecA` and `RecB` are defined

Comment: Also, is your function using shape properties for this determination? Like `.Left`, `.Top`, `.Width`, `.Height`?

Comment: If we don't know what `Overlap` expects for arguments, nor what types and values you're giving it, how are we supposed to be able to help you? Please [edit] your question to include the relevant information.

Comment: Also, if `MsgBox ("foobar")` is a habit, I invite you to take a look at *[This is confusing, why not just aways use parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses#t=201610110329089044336)* on Docs.SO.

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks for the tip, greatly appreciated. When is it even beneficial to use parentheses then?

Comment: @Tyeler What is the reasoning behind making it a private sub as opposed to public? Is it simply to quarantine the defined variables in case they interfere with other subs?

Comment: Event handlers handle events, they're private unless you make them public, which is bad code because no other code should need to directly call an event handler. Public/Private controls the accessibility of the procedure, not of its local variables. Locals are always local to the scope of the procedure they're declared in, regardless of the procedure's accessibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't properly defined your shapes. If your function is using object properties to determine the overlap, you'd need to do something like the following in your `CommandButton1_Click` event:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'Assumed on worksheet index 1
    Dim RecA As Shape: Set RecA = ws.Shapes("RecA") 'Assumed RecA is the name of your shape?
    Dim RecB As Shape: Set RecB = ws.Shapes("RecB")
    Dim Function_Result As Boolean

    Function_Result = Overlap(RecA, RecB) 

    If Function_Result = True Then
            MsgBox ("swiggity swooty")
    End If
End Sub
```

This way, you've set your shapes up as objects in VBA and can now reference their object properties.

Comment: That was my mistake. Thanks!

I also have answered my own question with all of my code for those who come after that may want to get a better picture.

Comment: You could remove the `=TRUE` part of the `If...Then` statement, or alternatively use `IF Overlap(RecA, RecB)  Then` and remove the `Function_Result` part altogether.

Answer (score 0):

**Code that works:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Function_Result As Boolean
    Dim RecA As Shape
    Dim RecB As Shape

    Function_Result = Overlap(RecA, RecB)

    If Function_Result = True Then
            MsgBox "swiggity swooty"
    End If
End Sub
```

I was able to keep it a little more simple than Tyeler's answer since I have `set` my shapes in my `Overlap` function itself (seen below).

```
Function Overlap(RecA As Shape, RecB As Shape) As Boolean

Dim Shp1Left As Single
Dim Shp1Right As Single
Dim Shp1Top As Single
Dim Shp1Bottom As Single

Dim Shp2Left As Single
Dim Shp2Right As Single
Dim Shp2Top As Single
Dim Shp2Bottom As Single

Dim HorOverlap As Boolean
Dim VertOverlap As Boolean

Set RecA = Sheet1.Shapes("RecA")
Set RecB = Sheet1.Shapes("RecB")

With RecA
    Shp1Left = .Left
    Shp1Right = .Left + .Width
    Shp1Top = .Top
    Shp1Bottom = .Top + .Height
End With

With RecB
    Shp2Left = .Left
    Shp2Right = .Left + .Width
    Shp2Top = .Top
    Shp2Bottom = .Top + .Height
End With
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' do they overlap horizontally?
If Shp1Left > Shp2Left Then
    If Shp1Left < Shp2Right Then
        HorOverlap = True
    End If
End If
If Shp1Left < Shp2Left Then
    If Shp1Right > Shp2Left Then
        HorOverlap = True
    End If
End If

' do they overlap vertically?
If Shp1Top > Shp2Top Then
    If Shp1Top < Shp2Bottom Then
        VertOverlap = True
    End If
End If
If Shp1Top < Shp2Top Then
    If Shp1Bottom > Shp2Top Then
        VertOverlap = True
    End If
End If

Overlap = HorOverlap And VertOverlap

End Function
```

Comment: Doing it this way there's no need to define `RecA` and `RecB` in the click event, just define them in Overlap and change the function to `Function Overlap() as boolean` - if you keep them in the click event though you could pass different shapes to the function from other procedures.